Slow boot - Ubuntu 24.04
I'm a beginner and I installed Ubuntu 24.04 recently, my boot time is high than before. I was using the previous LTE version (22.04) earlier which was pretty fast comparatively.
Here is my system details:
Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              HP HP Pavilion x360 Convertible 14-ba1xx
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i5-8250U × 8
Graphics:                                    NVIDIA GeForce 940MX
Graphics 1:                                  NVIDIA GeForce 940MX
Disk Capacity:                               1.1 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            F.54
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-31-generic

systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 6.369s (firmware) + 4.971s (loader) + 3.338s (kernel) + 30.987s (userspace) = 45.666s 
graphical.target reached after 30.866s in userspace.

systemd-analyze blame
19.014s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 7.467s NetworkManager.service
 7.272s snapd.seeded.service
 5.625s fwupd.service
 3.336s snapd.service
 2.557s apport.service
 1.896s udisks2.service
 1.437s gnome-remote-desktop.service
 1.417s power-profiles-daemon.service
 1.367s iio-sensor-proxy.service
 1.350s upower.service
 1.320s accounts-daemon.service
 1.290s polkit.service
 1.289s dev-sda2.device
 1.254s user@1000.service
 1.102s systemd-rfkill.service
 1.008s rsyslog.service
  995ms gpu-manager.service
  878ms ModemManager.service
  775ms systemd-logind.service
  628ms bluetooth.service
  584ms update-notifier-download.service
  513ms systemd-udev-trigger.service

systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @30.866s
└─multi-user.target @30.866s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @11.847s +19.014s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @11.694s +70ms
      └─network.target @11.611s
        └─NetworkManager.service @4.139s +7.467s
          └─dbus.service @3.972s +129ms
            └─basic.target @3.959s
              └─sockets.target @3.959s
                └─snapd.socket @3.950s +8ms
                  └─sysinit.target @3.942s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @5.807s +196ms
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @5.779s
                        └─system.slice @581ms
                          └─-.slice @581ms

Is there something I can do to make my system faster? Please let me know.

same issue, I ran  systemd-analyze plot > ~/SystemdAnalyzePlot.svg for a detail breakdown.
